# Bootstrap DataTable: Not searching inside <input> field

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying the functionalities of DataTable and I'm having the following issue:

This is an example of the data shown on the table:

[image]

As it can be seen, in the first column ("Serial"), there are two cases that begin with KD. Will try to search them:

[image]

In the result, none of them were found, I wonder how can this be fixed. As a side note, this column is marked as 'readonly' but that was not the issue.

This is the code that constructs the table:

```
<table id="management" class="table table-bordered table-hover" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th hidden>Hidden</th>
            <th class="col-md-3">Serial</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">Tienda</th>
            <th class="col-md-1">Precio</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">Estado</th>
            <th class="col-md-1">Update</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td hidden  >
                    <form id="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.Id))" asp-action="Management" asp-route-id="@item.Id" method="post">
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-3">
                    <input form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.Id))" type="hidden" asp-for="@item.Id" />
                    <div class="form-group" form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.Id))">
                        <div>
                            <input form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.Id))" asp-for="@item.MchName" name="MchName" readonly class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="@item.MchName" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group" form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.Id))">
                            <div>
                                <select asp-for="@item.StoreID" name="StoreID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.StoreID" form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.Id))"></select>
                                <span asp-validation-for="@item.StoreID" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group" form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.Id))">
                            <div>
                                <input type="number" max="10" min="0" step=".5" asp-for="@item.PUnit" name="PUnit" class="form-control" form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.Id))" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="@item.PUnit" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group" form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.Id))">
                            <div>
                                <select name="Status" asp-for="@item.MachineStatus" class="form-control" form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.Id))">
                                    <option value="0">Operativo</option>
                                    <option value="1">Nuevo Item</option>
                                    <option value="2">Reparación</option>
                                </select>
                                <span asp-validation-for="@item.MachineStatus" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-1">
                        <input form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.Id))" id="submit-data" type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default" />
                </td>
            </tr>}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Script of the DataTable:

```
<script>
        $("#management").DataTable();
</script>
```

This is the code of a constructed row:

[image]

Also, tried adding a row manually with simple text manually written and that was successfully filtered. *Maybe nothing that is inside an  can be read?*

Comment: don't add screenshot of the code. add code. also add your script code.

Comment: @ab29007 Sorry. Now it's added. Looks like the search option can't look into information that is inside a input field. Still looking for confirmation/solution. Thanks